# Relevance of Advanced Placement courses to graduate admissions

Tags: masters

So a lot of websites recommend taking AP courses and earning college credits in advance. What exactly are advanced placement courses and where can one take them ? Why are they stressed upon; are they really all that important a factor while considering students for admission to a Master's program?

Comment: Advanced Placement (AP) courses are taken by high school students in the US as a way of earning undergraduate college credits.  This isn't relevant to admission into a Master's program and is off topic for this site.

Comment: https://apstudent.collegeboard.org/home  AP is a system for getting college credit by examination instead of taking classes.  They are for bachelor's degrees, and as far as I know they are irrelevant to master's programs.

Comment: @BrianBorchers: Not directly, no. However, they __can__ have an influence. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, the [Advanced Placement](https://apstudent.collegeboard.org/) (AP) program offers students the opportunity to earn college credits for courses completed during high school by successfully passing an exam of difficult comparable to that of a college course.

*Directly*, AP courses do not influence graduate admissions, since they are generally excluded from cumulative averages. However, they *indirectly* can influence master's and PhD admissions, because the ability to place out of lower-level courses can open up the possibility to complete more advanced courses in a given discipline, or allow for enough "freedom" in the course plan to allow time for graduate-level coursework. For example, I had sufficient AP credits to opt out of a number of courses as an undergraduate; as a result of this, I was able to take three different graduate-level courses plus an advanced undergraduate math elective that otherwise I would not have had time for.

Comment: I strongly second the points in this answer! To reiterate: no, the literal getting of more undergrad credits does not affect graduate admission, but it makes _possible_ coursework and other activities that can _greatly_ enhance graduate admissions prospects. E.g., taking as many graduate-level courses as possible while an undergrad.